# How to add vertical line(a now pointer which lays over the layout) to a layout

Tags: android

The vertical line which points now stays over the layout. When I try to add a view with fill parent, the list view below it is not visible.

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you put up an image describing the result you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a view dynamically to layout using addVIew() option, added the drawables to view.

In my case, I need to show a pointer so i created a linear layout and added to parent at specified logic.